# Get value between parentheses

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get the all strings that sit between open and closed parentheses. An example string is as follows

> [CDATA[[(MyTag),xi(Tag2) ]OT(OurTag3).

The output needs to be an array with `MyTag`, `Tag2`, `OurTag3` i.e. The strings need to have the parentheses removed.

The code below works but retains the parentheses. How do I adjust the regex pattern to remove the parentheses from the output?

```
string pattern = @"\(([^)]*)\)";
string MyString = "[CDATA[[(MyTag),xi(Tag2) ]OT(OurTag3)";
Regex re = new Regex(pattern);
foreach (Match match in re.Matches(MyString))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); // print the captured group 1
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `string.Trim` on the result?

Comment: Are you parsing HTML or XML?  If so, there are much better options for both rather than use regex

Comment: I am parsing XML

Comment: [Where is the original code retaining parentheses](https://ideone.com/9vywzh)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
(?<=\().+?(?=\))
```

(?<=() - positive lookbehind for (

.*? - non greedy match for the content

(?=)) - positive lookahead for )

Comment: The original code works, why use lookarounds?

Comment: The original code retained the parentheses